# Android Spinner onItemSelected result to a textview?

Tags: android, spinner

I've got a spinner working where `onItemSelected` outputs a Toast. I want it to display a string value in a textview instead. So how would you rewrite the below method to show a string in a textview called denomiTV:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
View view, int pos, long id) { 
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext()), "Your Selection is: " + 
parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

I tried this, but Eclipse says that `.setText` is not correct here:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
View view, int pos, long id) { 
    denomiTV.setText(parent.getContext(), "Your selection is:" +
    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setText()`](http://goo.gl/liYNe) takes a single `CharSequence` argument... you shouldn't be passing in a `Context`.

```
denomiTV.setText("Your selection is:" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
```

Comment: Thank you. You've answered my question, but now the result shows up in the body of the spinner itself, not in the textview.

Comment: sounds like a layout problem then... the answer I just gave will set the text for the given textview. if the text isn't displaying the way you want it to, then it's probably a different issue.

Comment: You're right (again). It was a layout issue, the textview was behind the spinner so it looked like the text was inside the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `parent.getContext()` as a parameter for a TextView, take a look at [TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

This is what you want:

```
denomiTV.setText("Your selection is:" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code..

```
denomiTV.setText("Your Selection is : " + parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
```